# How to focus efficiently on the google search bar in vimperator?

Tags: firefox, vimperator, google-search

Search bars can normally be focused using `f` or `;;` and `<enter>`, but this doesn't work on the Google search bar for some reason.

Suppose I just did a search `:open hello world`, I currently do the following:

1. I would search via `/hello world`,
2. then navigate to the occurrence of the word in the google search bar,
3. then do `<C-t>` to be in vim normal mode to edit inside the input field.

But this is not very convenient.

Comment: In Pentadactyl `f` works with Google search bar correctly, perhaps, it is a good occasion to switch to it from Vimperator finally. Plus you might use `gi`.

Comment: I actually started out with Pentadactyl (at that moment aware of Vimperator and Vimium's existence and prefered the idea behind it) but later switched to Vimperator and I personally prefer it.

Comment: So did you try `gi` ? I use it with vimperator.

Comment: `gi` works : ). Could someone make a separate answer so I can accept it and you get the points?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gi`. This always works.

You can also use `i`. This will work perfectly on Google. `i` will take you to ignore mode, so the focus is completely with google. And Google has this feature that when you type on their page, the search bar automatically gains focus and you're in their search bar automagically.