# Give Vimperator key combinations (e.g. <C-i>) priority over all site specific ones

Tags: firefox, keyboard, javascript, vimperator

When in an input field the key combination `<C-I>` opens an instance of your editor where you can then write and save so the output is sent to the input field.

However, when I use this key combination in the *description input field of a stackoverflow question* (not the question title, but the body as the input I wrote this text in) then using this key combination will trigger adding emphasis signs (e.g. *some word*) instead.

How can I let the Vimperator key combination have priority over the Stackoverflow field one? I don't even need to have it for specific key combinations, just for all Vimperator key combinations at once is sufficient.

Is there some way that I can always give Vimperator key combinations priority over site specific ones?

Comment: In Pentadactyl it works correctly out of a box. Perhaps, it is [another](http://superuser.com/questions/823009/how-to-focus-efficiently-on-the-google-search-bar-in-vimperator) reason to update your Vimperator to Pentadactyl finally.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Also, see my answer to the comment you linked to.